# Lag issues with FontMetrics

Tags: java, awt, fontmetrics

From the Oracle documentation page on FontMetrics:

"Note that the implementations of these methods are inefficient, so they are usually overridden with more efficient toolkit-specific implementations."

Can anyone suggest any? The reason I ask is that I implemented fontMetrics to measure the width of a string, and it took about half a second to calculate it. Since I need to do this several times every time the window is painted, is there a way I can get the width of the string without getting insane lag?

In case I've actually just done something wrong, here's the code causing the lag:

```
g2d.setFont(new Font("Kootenay", Font.PLAIN, 20));
g2d.setColor(new Color(93, 138, 168));
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Could it be that it only took half a second the first time around, while it needed to load the font or something? Try it 10 times in a row and see if the numbers become better. Also, in my experience you won't necessarily get back the correct answer, it may be a few pixels off every now and again :(

Comment: @iluxa Hmm... you're right. I've set it to repaint when the frame is resized, and there's no lag then. Do you think I should load the fonts in a parent component then pass the metrics down in this component's constructor? Also, I don't really mind a few pixels of error.

Comment: Personally, I'd create a FontMetricsResolver singleton somewhere on the side. Now if all you usage comes from children of one parent component, shoving it there sounds fine

Comment: I've never heard of singletons before. So far, I've found pages and pages of discussion of whether they're worth using or not, but not much information on how to use them. Is there a tutorial or something you could link to?

Comment: Singletone guarantees you have a single instance of an object in your entire app. See here for example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html

Comment: Sorry for not responding quickly. Anyway, I think I now understand. Is it the case that I can access the singleton from one component, then get the singleton from a subcomponent in the same state without having to pass it down?

Comment: exactly. Singleton is basically a replacement for a class with all static methods, but with a singleton you get to control its lifecycle a bit. Don't abuse singletons, as they can be painful to unit-test

Comment: It's really tempting to just put them all over the place now...